# Window Event when "?" added after current URL

Tags: javascript, events, window

Hashchange is for when

```
index.php
```

Changes to, say

```
index.php#my-hash
```

i.e.

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
  // do stuff
});
```

But is there an event for when there is a ? after the url, i.e.

```
index.php?id=foo&something_else=bar...
```

**Edit**

Okay, it's when I submit a form. I submit the form and then the URL changes to

```
index.php?id=blah#my-hash
```

However I tried listening for a) the hashchange and b) the form submit:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
        go_to_signup_form();
});
```

Neither of which work (I think the page is refreshing?). I can't alter the php too much because it's part of a cms and I don't want to break anything that's happening in say, the controller class so I would rather just try to see when:

```
index.php
```

changes to

```
index.php?id=blah#my-hash
```

Edit #2 
Thanks everyone for the feedback, got it working with:

```
if (url.indexOf("?") !== -1) {
    go_to_signup_form();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, that is because the parameters (`?foobar`) aren't usually used for client-side code. Linking to a new parameter on the same url (`index.php -> index.php?foo=bar`) makes your browser load a new page, while adding a hash (`index.php -> index.php#foo=bar`) does not make the browser transmit any data to the server.

The hash section of a url, it's a client-side piece of data. As such, it is useful to have a `change` event listener for it.

Try these in your console, on a random site that doesn't have a hash in the url yet:

```
window.location.href += "?test"
```

and:

```
window.location.href += "#test"
```

You will see that the first one will reload the page (Send a new HTTP request), the second one will not appear to do anything.

To prevent a form from submitting:

```
$('#target').submit(function() {
    // Your onclick code here
    return false; // Do not submit.
});
```

Comment: My URL actually does something like index.php?id=something#my-hash but it doesn't seem to catch the hashchange event when this happens...?

Comment: If you're linking from the url, from `index.php`, it will reload the page first. Then, from the browser's point of view, the has hasn't changed.

Comment: Just add a event listener to the submit button, in that case.

Comment: @redconservatory: I added a piece of code to prevent the form from submitting.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with that is that the "hashchange" (technically it means navigation to an anchor) is an entirely client-sided operation. But an URL with arguments (the "?" operator) is fulfilled with a new HTTP request to the server, which results in a new document being sent to the user. That means when a user clicks on a link `index.php?id=foo`, the page is reloaded.

But you can check the arguments of the URL the page was loaded with by examining the `window.location.href` string.